# How to disable Specrun evaluation message

Tags: specflow

Is there a way I can disable the Specrun evaluation message as it takes an extra 15 seconds for this to be executed. I'm hoping to not execute this at all but I am unsure if this is not possible in free version?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a valid license to avoid the restrictions. You can request a 30 day trial [here](https://specflow.org/plus/request-trial/). Note that you cannot use the trial license for production purposes, the license is only for evaluation purposes.

If you want to use SpecFlow+ Runner for production purposes, you will need to purchase a license. You can do so in the online web shop (buy button on [this page](https://specflow.org/plus/)). If you are interested in more than just a handfull of licenses (5+), contact info [at] specflow.org instead.